# RestEasy Scanners stopping Tomcat Application

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, log4j, resteasy

problem:
**Hello folks after migrating from log4j 1.x version to log4j2.17.1 directly, my RestEasy scanners in web.xml file then they are breaking the tomcat application, Here are the logs attached, if I set them to false in web.xml application gets started but api's are not responding, getting 404 error.
I'am stuck on it for a week, please any help would be appreciated,**

LOGS:

```
07-Jan-2022 17:20:32.387 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
[DATETIME = 2022-01-07 17:20:33] [CLASS = Logger]  [METHOD = traceSimpleMessage] :: Loggerm
[DATETIME = 2022-01-07 17:20:33] [CLASS = Logger]  [METHOD = traceOut] :: Loggerm
[DATETIME = 2022-01-07 17:20:33] [CLASS = Logger]  [METHOD = traceOut] :: Loggerm
[DATETIME = 2022-01-07 17:20:33] [CLASS = com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]  [METHOD = <init>] :: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSourcem
[DATETIME = 2022-01-07 17:20:33] [CLASS = com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]  [METHOD = <init>] :: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSourcem
[DATETIME = 2022-01-07 17:20:33] [CLASS = Logger]  [METHOD = traceOut] :: Loggerm
[DATETIME = 2022-01-07 17:20:33] [CLASS = Logger]  [METHOD = traceOut] :: Loggerm
[DATETIME = 2022-01-07 17:20:33] [CLASS = com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]  [METHOD = <init>] :: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSourcem
[DATETIME = 2022-01-07 17:20:34] [CLASS = com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]  [METHOD = <init>] :: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSourcem
07-Jan-2022 17:20:34.117 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
07-Jan-2022 17:20:34.118 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/] startup failed due to previous errors
07-Jan-2022 17:20:34.126 WARNING [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesJdbc The web application [] registered the JDBC driver [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
07-Jan-2022 17:20:34.127 WARNING [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [mssql-jdbc-TimeoutTimer-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
 java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:460)
 java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:362)
 java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:941)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1073)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[2022-01-07 05:20:34,143] Artifact war exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
07-Jan-2022 17:20:39.439 INFO [Catalina-utility-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-tomcat-9.0.43\webapps\manager]
07-Jan-2022 17:20:39.597 INFO [Catalina-utility-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
07-Jan-2022 17:20:39.627 INFO [Catalina-utility-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-tomcat-9.0.43\webapps\manager] has finished in [188] ms
```

Comment: I'am using 2.2.1GA resteasy version

Comment: That is a very old version of RESTEasy and predates log4j2. You likely won't see logs from that version of RESTEasy because it can't find the log manager to bind to.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins after updating the RestEasy version many methods like PreProcessInterceptor is breaking up also

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins I want to migrate from log4j to log4j2 without updating resteasy version

Comment: If you use the log4j2/JUL integration that might work.

Comment: Nope still no luck

Comment: I'm not really too sure then. I don't know a lot about RESTEasy 2.2.x. I just know it uses it's own logging facade and that logging facade does not bind to log4j2.